# React Native: App gets stuck when using FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using a FlatList like below and the app gets stuck.

```
<FlatList
  data={this.getData()}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The FlatList `data` prop only works with an array, not an object.
Passing it an object causes some infinite loop that freezes the app.

The problem was that `getData()` was returning an object and not an array.